# insert an extra data inside an Object response in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my function

```
public function show(Course $course, Chapter $chapter)
{   $chapter_id=$chapter->id;
    $data= Content::with(['exercise','topic'])->where('chapter_id','=',$chapter_id)->get();
    $data['isviewed']=True;
    return $this->SuccessDataResponse($data);
}
```

Out Put is

```
{
"0": {
    "id": 1,
    "chapter_id": 1,
    "type": "topic",
    "topic_id": 1,
    "exercise_id": null,
    "exercise": null,
    "topic": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "chapter_id": 1,
        "type": "video",
        "pdf_url": "0",
        "video_url": "",
    }
},
**"isviewed": true**
```

}

**How can i Add the `"isviewed": true`** like below

```
 {
 {
    "id": 1,
    "chapter_id": 1,
    "type": "topic",
    "topic_id": 1,
    "exercise_id": null,
    "exercise": null,
    "isviewed": true,
    "topic": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 2,
        "chapter_id": 1,
        "type": "video",
        "pdf_url": "0",
        "video_url": "",
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)?

Comment: I was thinking that @brombeer, but there's nothing in the question about this being persistent and no data to base it on. It looks like OP just wants to set it in the controller as it's being viewed - not that that makes any sense!

Answer (score 0):

try like this one:

```
public function show(Course $course, Chapter $chapter)
{   $chapter_id=$chapter->id;
    $data= Content::with(['exercise','topic'])->where('chapter_id','=',$chapter_id)->get();
   
    $result = array_merge($data,['isviewed' => true]);
    return $this->SuccessDataResponse($result );
}
```

Comment: `array_merge` needs two (or more) arrays as inputs, so you'd want `array_merge($data, ['isviewed' => true])`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to set `is_viewed` in the controller without actually persisting the data anywhere - you may as well just hard-code it in the view.

Assuming what you actually want to do is save `is_viewed` on the course, you'd need to add the field to the database.

First, create a new migration:

```
php artisan make:migration add_is_viewed_to_course_table
```

Then, in your new migration file, add the field:

```php
$table->boolean('is_viewed');
```

Then migrate:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Next, in your controller, set the field to true:

```php
$course->is_viewed = true;
$course->save();
```

*Notes*

There are a few other things you may want to look at:

- Is it really the course that you want to mark as viewed, and not the chapter?
- When you call `Content::with`, you could potentially get more than one returned. You need to choose which one to mark as viewed.
- You should try to keep your syntax consistent - in your model, your fields have underscores but then you've said `isviewed`, so I changed it to `is_viewed` in my solution

Comment: i Just want to pass the value true only to the api . I dont want to store it in my database table
@adam